# How to create an empty file in golang at a specified path. Lets say at $HOME/newFile.txt

Tags: go

Trying to create a new file at a specified path. I tried using filepath.abs() but it doesn't give the absolute path.

For example:

```
filePath, _ := filepath.Abs("$HOME/internship.txt")                       
f, err := os.Create(filePath)
```

this code doesnt give me the absolute path of $HOME/internship.txt; instead it gives me the path of the current directory plus $HOME/internship.txt

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: sorry about that I edited my post/

Comment: Have you checked the value of `err`? Also note that filepath functions do not resolve environment variables, and that it is generally a good idea to use `filepath.FromSlash()` and `filepath.ToSlash()` whenever you come from and go to a generic forward slash-representation of a path, in order to remain multi-platform.

Comment: Go is not a shell and will not evaluate shell variables such as $HOME. Use [os.UserHomeDir](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#UserHomeDir).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use "os" library(the one you already imported). Example:

```
filePath, _ := filepath.Abs(os.Getenv("HOME") + "/internship.txt")
```

or (As Peter said)

```
home, _ := os.UserHomeDir()
filePath, _ := filepath.Abs(home + "/internship.txt")
```

Go is not a Unix shell.